# How to change the background color of a row in RDLC report on mouse over?

Tags: reporting-services, reporting

I am working on RDLC reporting.Processing mode is local.

I have a requirement that I need to change the background color of a row in RDLC report on mouse over.

Please tell me how to do this?

Regards,

N.SRIRAM

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that it is impossible.